# Setting Background of card View and scroll animations

Tags: android, scroll

Also I was trying to set background of my a card View used in recycler view in my app for that i did the following

card xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

    android:layout_height="120dp"

    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_card_subject"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:id="@+id/home_card_subject_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/subject_text"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="70"/>
        <TextView
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:id="@+id/home_card_credits"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4 credits"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="30"
           />


    </LinearLayout
        >
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

dashboard fragment:

```
package com.example.app100.ui.home;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
    LinearLayout cardView;
    private ArrayList<Subject> subject = new ArrayList<>();
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
        populateArrayList();


    //homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);


        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        cardView =  root.findViewById(R.id.home_card_subject);
        /*final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });*/
        Random rand = new Random();

        int rand_int1 = rand.nextInt(3);


        switch (rand_int1){
            case 0:
                cardView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_color1);
                break;
            case 1:
                cardView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_color2);
                break;
            case 2:
                cardView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_color3);
                break;
        }


        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.home_recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext() , LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL , false));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter(subject));

 //       recycle.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager( getActivity(),2));
//          recycle.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter(subList));

        return root;
    }


    private void populateArrayList(){
        Log.d(TAG , "populating array list");

        Cursor data = databaseHelper.getdata();
        while(data.moveToNext()){
            Subject sub = new Subject(data.getString(0) , data.getInt(1), data.getInt(2),
                    data.getInt(3), data.getInt(4),data.getInt(5) , data.getInt(6));
            subject.add(sub);
        }
    }
}
```

but doing this gave the following errors:

```
2020-04-09 12:18:18.142 15575-15575/com.example.app100 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.app100, PID: 15575
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.app100.ui.home.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:65)
```

I wanted a scroll effect where the bottom part scrolls over the the top part like in the image bellow[like the image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4peS.jpg) the whiete part would scroll over the purple part and not scroll with it.

Comment: the id you are getting is of liner layout, not the card view. and you can change the background by setting the carview cardbackgroud tint.

Comment: i am using a lineat layout inside the cardview which is covering the entire card so i am setting the color of the the linear layout can you please explain a little more.

Comment: so why you dont change the cardview backgroud, instead of linear layout ?\

Comment: i tried that but it gave the same error

Comment: cardviewsetCardBackgroundColor(getRandomColorCode())

Answer (score 0):

You are did not defined any id to cardview, and give linear layout reference to the cardview so cardview become null and occur Null pointer Exception. Please set id to cardView and give that id reference to the cardView.

Comment: I declared a linear layout named cardview and then did findViewById for linear layout and i am trying to set the color of the entire linear layout but it is not working can you please explain a little more

Comment: use this code to set the background color of the linearLayout            linear.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity,R.color.black)); where linear pass id of your linear layout